# parameter getting wrong value in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax

I have following ajax call , in that call I'm passing `product_ID` and `type`
values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var samplevariable = @ViewBag.Sample_ID;
$('#input-samplelocation').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Home")',
    data: {
      product_ID: samplevariable,
      type: "string_value"
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json"
  });
});

</script>
```

This is the controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(string product_ID , string type)
{
     .....
}
```

currently this approach working properly , but if this `@ViewBag.Sample_ID` equal to `08` when It passing to `Create` method I can see `product_ID` value as `8` not `08` ,

How can I bind the exact similar value ?

Comment: you are passing it as string try passing as `int`

Comment: @guradio how can I do that ?

Comment: @guradio There's no data typing in POST parameters, everything is a string.

Comment: @Barmar i see :) it was a wild guess it was way off then :)

Comment: Your JS variable is a number. Declare it as a string. `var samplevariable = '@ViewBag.Sample_ID';`

Comment: @nnnnnn i think he is passing it now as string because `08` if it was number then he would have got `8` right?

Comment: @nnnnnn doesn't I declared everything as a strings ?

Comment: Try putting `@ViewBag.Sample_ID` in quotes.

Comment: @Barmar Double quotes or Single quotes ?

Comment: interesting, any quotes if that doesn't help try stringify json object

Comment: Double or single is fine, assuming the actual value won't include any quote characters.

Comment: They're both the same in Javascript.

Comment: What is all the @ stuff, is that JSP or .NET or something like that?

Comment: .Net , its worked @Barmar why don't you post as answer happy to accept it

Comment: don't forget to put the script in a document ready statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `.NET` variable in quotes, so it won't be interpreted as a number, which causes leading zeroes to be removed.

```
var samplevariable = '@ViewBag.Sample_ID';
```